# Duplicate Firebase Data Tree

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

On the Firebase website is there anyway to duplicate a data structure tree? I'm going to need to reuse the 'format' of the tree multiple times so being able to duplicate quickly would be a lot easier than having to recreate each child over and over again.
[image: database tree]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the console doesn't offer that feature. Is there a reason you can't write a quick app to do it? It's about 5 lines of code (in Swift).

Comment: Do you mean an interactive tree that allows you to modify and instantly see changed values (even from others), add new values and instantly show them in the tree (even from others)?? (Because that's what I'm searching for, and am just looking if someone has done it before to avoid some time loss)

Comment: No I was just trying to duplicate a section of a tree @davidtaubmann

Comment: LOL... ok... then tyour answer is fine. I'm developing a duplicate of Firebase's Console Database Tree... Maybe you should add the word "information" or "data" to the title of your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, building a small app to do this would solve the problem. I did find another way to to this, I exported the whole tree as JSON then edited it and re-uploaded it.